# Blazor @onkeydown event pass event parameter to JS function

Tags: c#, blazor

With .NET 5.0 released, we as Blazor developers can now use JavaScript module isolation. Because I have a lot of `.js` files, I want to use isolation to let each component use its own javascript functions.

I do have a problem now though with the `event` parameter.
This is how it currently works:

**Main.razor**

```
<input id="numInput" onkeydown="NumericInputExensions.NumericKeyDown(event)">
```

**Script.js**

```
window.NumericInputExensions = {

  // Handle numeric input
  NumericKeyDown: function (event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
        return; // Do nothing if event already handled
    }
    if (event.metaKey || event.altKey || event.ctrlKey) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Check if event.key is numeric
    if (/^[\d]$/.test(event.key)) {
        return;
    }

    event.preventDefault(); // All other keys will be prevented here
    return;
  }
}
```

So whenever the input key is pressed down, the input could be prevented if it is not numeric.

However, with the new JavaScript module isolation, the JS function will be invoked. So instead of directly calling the `NumericKeyDown` function, the `input` element now first does the following:

**NEW Main.razor**

```
<input id="numInput" @onkeydown="@OnKeyDown">

@code {
    private Task<IJSObjectReference> m_Module;
    private Task<IJSObjectReference> Module => m_Module ??= JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./scripts/Script.js").AsTask();

    async void OnKeyDown (KeyboardEventArgs args) {
        var module = await Module;
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("NumericKeyDown", args);
    }
}
```

This works well, until the part where in the `NumericKeyDown`, the `event` parameter can't be used anymore:

[image]

How can I use/pass the `event` so JavaScript can handle the `event.preventDefault`?

Comment: Is there a constraint on using Blazor's own preventdefault?

Comment: Yes, because I don't want to preventDefault everything from the start. Keys like Tab etc need to be prevented in the browser.

Comment: And you can't set preventDefault during the event (using a Boolean value), because it needs to be done before the event triggers

Comment: You preventdefault and capture event args in blazor event handler. Inside the event handler invoke the js function as usual.

Comment: That does not work